# How to expose nodejs api on namecheap VPS server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, namecheap

I have purchased a subscription to NameCheap VPS service.
I have nodejs api running locally that I want to expose. 
Currently when visiting mydomain.com a  static page is served. How do I expose my nodejs api and handle requests to for example mydomain.com/books?

I have run the steps descrived [here](https://tecadmin.net/install-latest-nodejs-and-npm-on-centos/)

The following guide is [useless.](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/10047/2182/how-to-work-with-nodejs-app)

Comment: What do you mean expose? Like callable directory from front end? Or do you simply mean you need to run your nodejs scripts? If its the last you have to execute your js script in some server terminal connection(ssh session etc), eg `node myscriptapp.js`

Comment: Note for your server it looks like your cpanel can load your js scripts. Just upload your script follow the steps in  the create application section setting the "Application startup file" to the file you uploaded. And tell it to `start`

Comment: no I know how to run my scripts. I can access my api locally. Calling localhost:3000/books locally gives me what I am looking for. Not sure how to have the same happen when I call mydomain.com/books

Comment: @PatrickEvans can you show me where I can find the application section of cPanel? This is my view - https://imgur.com/yZZ9AT2.

Comment: the "useless" guide shows you. Find the section labeled "software" then find the item named "setup node js app" and click it, then click "create application button" fill out the for setting your script file in the right field. If the "setup nodejs app" isnt visible contact your server company's support team and ask them if something isnt setup right

Comment: If you manually installed nodejs then you would probably need to manually run the scripts as manually added software isnt usually picked up by cpanel software. That company might also have nodejs only usable with certain purchased packages. Again ask their support team